# How to get my Teclast X98 plus 2 built in touch screen working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: touchscreen

I have a teclast x98plus 2 on which I installed Ubuntu 20.04. Everything works except the built in touchscreen. I have looked at many fora but unable to find how I can fix this issue.
Touch is supposed to be built in but how can I check if the software is seeing the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the silead folder from https://github.com/onitake/gsl-firmware/tree/master/firmware/linux into /lib/firmware and reboot.

Regards!